# WebRTC fails to play the stream from remote peer after setting the video.srcObject property

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-streaming

I'm currently creating a simple home surveillance system, where I would enter the app as an streamer or as a consumer.

**Technologies**

- socket.io - for signaling between streamer and connected peer
- basic vite app - react
- webrtc to create a streaming channel between 2 peers

Only localhost is used for development purposes.
I'm running both the client and server from a Windows' WSL terminal.
The app is accessed from the Windows machine.

**Current behaviour**

After accessing to http://localhost/?stream I begin the streaming and wait for incoming messages from the websocket to start signaling with new peers.

When the consumer accesses http://localhost the WebRTC connection is performed and the tracks are received from the streamer side.

`peerConnection.ontrack` event on the consumer side is actually triggered, but the media stream seems to only contain 1 video track which is muted.

On the streamer side when doing `peerConnection.addTrack` I'm actually setting 2 tracks, one for the video and another for the audio.

**Problem**

When the consumer receives the tracks/stream from streamer, it sets it to the `video.srcObject` property, but nothing happens. No video nor audio is played.

**Expected behaviour**

The video and audio from the streamer should be played on the consumer side after receiving the tracks/stream and setting it to the consumer's `video.srcObject` property.

**What I've tried**

I have navigated the various related questions on StackOverflow, and I tried applying the various fixes which were suggested, but none of them worked properly.

- setting the video element autoPlay, playsInline and muted to true
- playing the video element programatically after setting the remote `video.srcObject`
- using a STUN server - but I believe that's not a requirement because I'm using localhost and not connecting 2 peers on the wide area network / internet.
- connecting the peers asynchronously after clicking a button on the consumer side - to not to try to play a video without user interaction.

**Code**

I will post below the application files involved in the main application logic:

Don't worry, this repo is indeed a very basic and minimal example of the problem (it's not that massive).

***Signaling Websocket service***

```js
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const io = new Server();

let streamer = null;
let users = new Set();

io.on("connect", (socket) => {
  if (users.has(socket.id)) {
    return;
  }

  console.log(
    `Socket ${socket.id} connected - Client IP Address: ${socket.handshake.address}`
  );

  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log(`Socket: ${socket.id} disconnected - Reason: ${reason}`);
  });

  socket.on("begin-stream", () => {
    console.log("begin stream", socket.id);
    streamer = socket.id;
  });

  socket.on("request-start-stream", (data) => {
    console.log("request-start-stream");
    socket.to(streamer).emit("handle-request-start-stream", {
      to: socket.id,
      offer: data.offer,
    });
  });

  socket.on("response-start-stream", (data) => {
    console.log("response-start-stream");
    socket.to(data.to).emit("handle-response-start-stream", data.answer);
  });
});

io.listen(5432, { cors: true });
```

***Streamer.tsx***

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

import socket from "./socket";
import useVideo from "./useVideo";

export default function Streamer() {
  const { videoRef, element: videoElement } = useVideo();

  useEffect(() => {
    init();

    async function init() {
      if (!videoRef.current) return;

      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      });

      videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;

      socket.emit("begin-stream");

      socket.on("handle-request-start-stream", async ({ to, offer }) => {
        const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
        stream
          .getTracks()
          .forEach(
            (track) =>
              console.log("track", track) ||
              peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream)
          );

        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(offer)
        );

        const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(answer)
        );
        socket.emit("response-start-stream", { to, answer });
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return videoElement;
}
```

***Consumer.tsx***

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

import socket from "./socket";
import useVideo from "./useVideo";

export default function Consumer() {
  const { videoRef, element: videoElement } = useVideo();

  useEffect(() => {
    init();

    async function init() {
      const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
      peerConnection.addEventListener("track", ({ streams: [stream] }) => {
        if (!videoRef.current) return;
        console.log('stream', stream)

        videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      });

      const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer({
        // workaround to receive the tracks
        // if this is not specified, I will never receive the tracks
        offerToReceiveAudio: true,
        offerToReceiveVideo: true,
      });
      await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(offer)
      );
      socket.emit("request-start-stream", { offer });

      socket.on("handle-response-start-stream", async (answer) => {
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(answer)
        );
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return videoElement;
}
```

***useVideo.tsx*** (video tag hook)

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function useVideo() {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  const element = <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay />;

  return { videoRef, element };
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the video tag?

Comment: Hello @TheKNVB - I have added the video tag hook in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the cause of the bug.

The ICE Candidate exchange logic was missing and I only had to add it.

***Signaling service***

```js
socket.on("send-candidate", (data) => {
  socket.to(data.to).emit("handle-send-candidate", data.candidate);
});
```

***Streamer.tsx***

```js
peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", (event) => {
  if (event.candidate === null) {
    return;
  }

  socket.emit("send-candidate", {
    to,
    candidate: event.candidate,
  });
});
```

***Consumer.tsx***

```js
socket.on("handle-send-candidate", (candidate) => {
  peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
});
```